# RabbitMQ DeliveryTag always 1

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, amqp

**SEE UPDATE**

I have RabbitMQ installed on my local machine and can queue messages without any problem.

I am using the RabbitMQ approved .NET Client library.

After Dequeueing a message AND successfully processing it our plan was to acknowledge the Message using BasicAck and passing of the DeliveryTag. This does not seem to work as the messages all return to the ready state.

Looking at the value of DeliveryTag after a BasicGet it is ALWAYS 1. I am sure this is wrong as how could I possibly pass that Tag back on BasicAck and expect a message to be uniquely identified.

What am I doing wrong? DeliveryTag should be a unique reference and not "1" yes?

**UPDATE**

I was recreating Channel every time so the call to BasicGet and the call to BasicAck  were on different Channels. Once I reused the Channel the messaged were successfully moved through Ready -> Uacked -> Off the Q.

FWIW the DeliveryTag is still 1

Unless someone wants to tell me that I should not be reusing Channels I think this is now answered. I am aware of the possible multithreaded issues with reusing Channels.

Thanks

Pat

Comment: Actually, delivery-tag=1 means "up to and including" (see http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1reference.html#basic.ack.delivery-tag), so in general you still can acknowledge messages, but the whole situation is a bit strange, maybe .NET guys provide more details?

Comment: When we call channel.BasicGet I pass false for noAck so I assume that is a no to "do you use auto-ack". If we pass true the DeliveryTag is still 1 but messages to leave the queue. Looking at the docs it seems that multiple = 1 means "up to and including" rather than DeliverTag. http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html. Do i need to Dequeue and BadsicAclk on the same Channel and Connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was recreating Channel every time so the call to BasicGet and the call to BasicAck were on different Channels. Once I reused the Channel the messaged were successfully moved through Ready -> Uacked -> Off the Q.

FWIW the DeliveryTag is still 1

Unless someone wants to tell me that I should not be reusing Channels I think this is now answered. I am aware of the possible multithreaded issues with reusing Channels.

Thanks

Pat